# Default vs optional function parameters with type hints

Tags: python, type-hinting, type-annotation

So the function `gendata` accepts two optional parameters (`name` and `source`) and then based on the value of `source` invokes `parser` with the same parameters that are however required in this function.

1. What is the recommended way to solve the required vs. none required parameters?
2. There is an example in Python docs for [typing.Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) and it shows that `Type[SuperClass]` should accept all child classes that inherit from it. Why `mypy` complains in this case and why only for arg 1 and 2 but not 3 (`source`)?

**exmaple.py:**

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List, Optional, Type


@dataclass
class BaseItem:
    name: str
    value: int


@dataclass
class Item(BaseItem):
    pass


@dataclass
class AnotherItem(BaseItem):
    pass


def parser(item: Type[BaseItem], name: str, source: int) -> Type[BaseItem]:
    item.value = source
    return item


def gendata(
    items: List[Item], name: Optional[str] = None, source: Optional[int] = None
) -> None:
    for item in items:
        if source:
            item = parser(item, name, source)
```

**Testing:**

```
$ mypy example.py 
e.py:31: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Type[BaseItem]", variable has type "Item")
e.py:31: error: Argument 1 to "parser" has incompatible type "Item"; expected "Type[BaseItem]"
e.py:31: error: Argument 2 to "parser" has incompatible type "Optional[str]"; expected "str"
Found 3 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Answer (score 5):

First thing, about the `Type[Something]` errors, according to the documentation, you should use `Type[Something]` when you're receiving the type as parameter, if you're receiving an instance of `BaseItem`, you should just use `BaseItem`.

Example:

```
a = 3         # Has type 'int'
b = int       # Has type 'Type[int]'
c = type(a)   # Also has type 'Type[int]'
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type

---

About the `Optional` error, I usually read optional as **nullable** (in the documentation they even say `Optional[X]` is equivalent to `Union[X, None]`.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional

So if you're receiving a parameter with type `Optional[str]` and try to pass to a function that receives a `str`, this will raise an error, one solution is just check if the value is `None` and put a default string instead, like:

```
def gendata(
    items: List[Item], name: Optional[str] = None, source: Optional[int] = None
) -> None:
    if name is None:
        name = ''
    if source:
        for item in items:
            item = parser(item, name, source)
```

Comment: One further note: `mypy` can infer `Optional[str]` from a default value of `None` in `name: str = None`.